# Display Json in search field in laravel or Php

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I need to display searched value on search bar.

My controller code :

```
$q = Input::get('q');
  $query = Jobs::select('job_title')->Where('job_title', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
  return response()->json($query);
```

My jquery axios code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jobsearch").keyup(function(){
     url = "{{route('searchexistingjob')}}";
     var word = $("#jobsearch").val();
     const data = {
       'q' : word
     }
     axios.post(url,data).then(response =>{
        for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
            // $('#jobsearch').val(response.data[i].value);           
     });
  });
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<input type="text" id="txtjobsearch" name="txtjobsearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Job title, designation, description..." autocomplete="off" data-id="1">
```

all the thing are correct only but i need how to display that value in search box any ideas?

Comment: http://www.expertphp.in/article/manual-laravel-autocomplete-search-from-database try this link

Comment: but i need to doo through axios that one working

Comment: you are using Vue.js?

Comment: try `{{ request()->input('q') }}` for the query variable `q` in your view

Comment: i have no knowledge of vue.js but if you want to do with jquery i have add the above link it will helps you i used to do in that way only

Comment: that one i already done its working fine but i need to doo this way this is my problem - don't consider this axios  - response.data[i].job_title my output is there but how to display in search field that only i don't know

Comment: I don't think putting 12 question marks after questions is going to achieve desired results.

Comment: Dude, you have no idea, you need a plugin that does it now. https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/

Answer (score 0):

If can you can change the response format

```
$q = Input::get('q');
$query = Jobs::select('job_title')->Where('job_title', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
return response()->json([
    search_terms => $q,
    results => $query,
]);
```

Or as you are using ajax, you already have the search term:

So instead of:

```
$('#jobsearch').val(response.data[i].value);
```

You will use:

```
$('#jobsearch').val(word);
```

Or just remove the line and leave what is already typed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a few easy steps.

Make a route, with same link, controller and function, just use POST method.
Wrap input field in the form, and when its submitted, let it go to the same page.
Create the variable in that controller@function, let's say:

> $result = "";

And pass that variable to the view.
And in the view, set the value of that input to the $result;

If its not queried yet, that input will be clear($result = '';), otherwise, it will display result of that query.

```
// routes/web.php 
Route::get('/home', 'SearchBarController@index');
Route::post('/home', 'SearchBarController@index');

// app/Http/Controllers/SearchBarController.php
public function index()
{
    $result = '';
    if(request()->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $q = Input::get('textjobsearch');
        $query = Jobs::select('job_title')->where('job_title', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
        $result = json_encode($query);
    }

    return view('searchbar.index', compact('result'));
}

// resources/views/searchbar/index.blade.php

<form method='post'>
    <input type="text" id="txtjobsearch" name="txtjobsearch" value="{{ $result }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Job title, designation, description..." autocomplete="off" data-id="1">
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

That's it.

That simple.